# Import errors after upgrading to sklearn 0.15

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

Using Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit and python 2.7.5. I've been using sklearn 0.14 for quite some time. After upgrading to version 0.15 via:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

I've encountered the following:

`from sklearn import svm`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "sklearn/svm/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import libsvm_sparse
  File "libsvm_sparse.pyx", line 5, in init sklearn.svm.libsvm_sparse (sklearn/svm/libsvm_sparse.c:6773)
  File "sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array, check_arrays, safe_asarray,
  File "sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .fixes import safe_copy
  File "sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .testing import ignore_warnings
  File "sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 36, in <module>
    from nose.tools import assert_equal
ImportError: No module named nose.tools
```

Then, if I try again -

```
from sklearn import svm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "sklearn/svm/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError: cannot import name libsvm
```

Importing sklearn itself does not raise ImportErrors.

Other answers to similar questions suggested uninstalling and re-installing, which helped others, but not in my case.

Edit:
after uninstalling and re-installing several times, including uninstalling and re-installing scikit-image, the problem seems to have passed, or at least change.
I now get the following:

```
from sklearn import svm
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:24: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from . import vonmises_cython
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:188: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from ._rank import rankdata, tiecorrect
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py:28: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from . import _ppoly
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:90: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .ckdtree import *
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:91: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .qhull import *
```

(I am using numpy 1.8.1)

However, other than the warnings, things look like they are working.
I don't know what caused the problem, or what amended it. Maybe installing sklearn first, and then skimage...

Edit 2:
Problem has been solved by completely removing scipy and numpy (including manually removing them from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ and /usr/share/pyshared/).

Comment: do you have `libsvm`?

Comment: I did not install it explicitly. IIRC, sklearn installs it implicitly. This is also how I used it until today.

Comment: I understand that but I am wondering if you are having an import error or if `libsvm` exists at all

Comment: I see. I think libsvm was installed. As you can see by my edit, it seems to have been solved, other than the runtime warnings I am now getting.

Comment: There is no dependency between scikit-learn and scikit-image. They should not influence each other. The warnings you get are odd. What version of scipy and numpy do you have and how did you build them? Scipy seems to be build with a different version of numpy than you are using right now.

Comment: I am using numpy 1.8.1 and scipy 0.14.0.
I installed them using pip.
Also, I ran scipy.test() and got an "OK"
(OK (KNOWNFAIL=278, SKIP=1163)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=16581 errors=0 failures=0>

Comment: Do you have a copy of Ubuntu's packaged NumPy and SciPy installed as well? It looks like those are not installed correctly and/or the scikit-learn build picked up the wrong NumPy.

Comment: I don't know which package was at fault, but by completely removing numpy and scipy (including manually removing the leftover files after pip uninstall), the problem was solved.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems something is wrong with the dependency packages when installing scikitlearn (although it didn't happen before for me too). I installed nose by running

```
pip install nose
```

and the error went away. Hope this helps.